# How would I create a nested set materialized view in postresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, nested-sets

I have hierarchical parent child data. I would like there to be a nested set view into that data which I could query. It seems that the safest way to maintain this nested set view into the table is for it actually be a postgresql view of raw data.

```
raw_data (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    parent INTEGER NULL
)
```

I am looking for a way to transform `raw_data` in `nested_set_view` as part of a view create statement.

```
nested_set_view (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    lft INTEGER NOT NULL,
    rgt INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

For some reason I am imagining that this might be easier or more efficient if `nested_set_view` were like

```
nested_set_view (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    lft INTEGER NOT NULL,
    rgt INTEGER NOT NULL,
    root INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Why not a RECURSIVE CTE instead? No relational integrity with Nested Set.

Comment: My intention is to use a common table expression in the query that creates my materialized `nested_set_view`. Maybe my question is more like "how do I create recursive query using cte which generates a nested set data structure?".

Comment: Creating a closure table using CTE is much less complicated and might be enough to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

CAVEAT(s)

1. verify that your Postgres version supports materialized views !
2. remember that you cannot update (directly) a materialized view

This is how we implemented a structure pretty much similar to the one you are proposing

The following code block creates the materialized view:

```
WITH
    RECURSIVE cell_paths
    (
        id_cell  ,
        id_parent,
        id_path  ,
        name_path
    ) AS
    (
     SELECT
                tbl_cell.pkid                  ,
                tbl_cell.fk_parent             ,
                ARRAY[tbl_cell.pkid]      AS "array",
                ARRAY[tbl_cell.cell_name] AS "array"
           FROM
                tbl_cell
          WHERE
                (
                    tbl_cell.fk_parent IS NULL)
  UNION ALL
     SELECT
                tbl_cell.pkid                          ,
                tbl_cell.fk_parent                     ,
                (cell_paths_1.id_path || tbl_cell.pkid),
                (cell_paths_1.name_path || tbl_cell.cell_name)
           FROM
                (cell_paths cell_paths_1
           JOIN
                tbl_cell
             ON
                ((
                        tbl_cell.fk_parent = cell_paths_1.id_cell)))
          WHERE
                (
                    NOT (
                        tbl_cell.pkid = ANY (cell_paths_1.id_path)))
    )
SELECT
        cell_paths.id_cell  ,
        cell_paths.id_parent,
        (
         SELECT
                    COUNT(*) AS COUNT
               FROM
                    tbl_cell x
              WHERE
                    ((
                            cell_paths.id_cell = x.pkid)
                        AND (
                            EXISTS
                            (
                             SELECT
                                        1
                                   FROM
                                        tbl_cell y
                                  WHERE
                                        (
                                            x.pkid = y.fk_parent))))) AS has_child,
        cell_paths.id_path                                                        ,
        cell_paths.name_path                                                      ,
        array_to_string(cell_paths.name_path, ' -> '::text) AS string_path
   FROM
        cell_paths
   ORDER BY
        cell_paths.id_path;
```

The following function will be called whenever we need to update the view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."fn_refresh_mvw_cellpath" ()  RETURNS trigger
VOLATILE
AS $dbvis$
BEGIN
                    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW mvw_cellpath;
                    RETURN NEW;
                    END;
$dbvis$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

As you can tell from the function definition we decided that an update of the view must occur whenever a change is made to a table. In this case our table tbl_cell

```
CREATE TRIGGER "tr_refresh_mvw_cellpath"
  AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON tbl_cell
  FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_refresh_mvw_cellpath()
```

This trigger will execute the refresh view call on every update or insert of our tbl_cell. This way we are guaranteed that the materialized view is up to date. Of course is it up to you to decide whether the cost of running the refresh is worth it. May be you only need to update the view once a day or ....

Hope this helps.

(exciting: my first post to stackoverflow. Hope I did it in the correct way.)

Comment: What is the final data structure? How could I get all the ancestors of an item in a single query? How could I get all the descendants of an item in a single query?